# Why doesn't setting "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD" work?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to let all containers in my kubernetes cluster access postgresql without password. So I set `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD` to "trust" (setting the environment variable). I expect `postgres` to change the default `pg_hba.conf` and append "`host all all all trust`" to the end of the file:

```
echo "host all all all $POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD" >> pg_hba.conf
```

According to [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), It has to do so. But `pg_hba.conf` doesn't get changed. Here is the end of my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

As you can see, this is the default `pg_hba.conf`.
How am I supposed to change this default `pg_hba.conf`?

***UPDATE***

I figured out that the problem is more fundamental. Postgres doesn't even create the postgres database. Please checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507573/why-doesnt-postgres-create-the-database):

Comment: Did you try replace pg_hba.conf file while building?

Comment: @MustafaGüler Not yet. I'm going to try it. thanks!